# Convert from void * to pointer to struct C++

Tags: struct, casting, pthreads, parameter-passing, void-pointers

I'm using pthreads to pass multiple parameters to a function by way of a struct.  I'm attempting to convert the struct I pass in using a conversion from void * to struct thread_args *.  This is giving me an error.  Can someone please explain how to manage this in C++.

Here is my code:

```
  struct thread_args
{
    int customer_num;
    int res_vector[NUMBER_OF_RESOURCES];
};

typedef struct thread_args theArgs;

int request_resources(int customer_num, int request[]);
int release_resources(int customer_num, int release[]);
void req_converter( void * x );
void rel_converter( void * x );

void req_converter( void * x )
{
    theArgs * args = dynamic_cast<theArgs *>(x); //(struct arg_struct *) x;
    request_resources( x.customer_num, x.res_vector);
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘x’ (of type ‘void*’) to type ‘theArgs* {aka struct thread_args*}’ (source is not a pointer to class)
```

Can someone please explain the best way to pass a struct using pthreads to a function that will use the struct parameters to call a second function with multiple parameters in C++?

Comment: Sugggestions: 1) `theArgs * args = static_cast<theArgs *>(x)`, and 2) `request_resources( args->customer_num, args->res_vector)`

Comment: Ah, that did it.  Thanks.  Can you explain why dynamic_cast doesn't work in this situation?